# Curl Command via Zapier to Create Stripe Invoice with Params

Tags: json, stripe-payments, webhooks, zapier

I'm attempting to create a Stripe Invoice using the Curl command in Zapier, but am getting a (400) Bad Request - "Invalid request (check your POST parameters): unable to parse JSON request body". The arguments i'm passing seem pretty straightforward so i'm not sure if i'm missing something or if i'm not formatting something correctly.

[image: Stripe Invoice Docs]

[image: Zapier Curl to Stripe]

Comment: Hey @csakon, one thing you might try is changing the data to urlencoded form and setting the content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

So data would be something like `customer=cus_123&application_fee_amount=10000`

Comment: @xavdid can you chime in here?

Comment: Hey Chad. Sorry I didn't see this! I was on vacation and weirdly, stackoverflow `@mentions` don't actually tag the user. In any case, I don't see anything immediately wrong above. I'd try sending that curl at https://httpbin.org and then doing the same for zapier and seeing if there's any meaningful difference between the two requests.

Comment: Much thanks! Will try