# Create Stripe refund using Custom Request in Zapier

Tags: stripe-payments, zapier

I'm trying to create a [Stripe refund](https://stripe.com/docs/api/refunds) using webhooks and Custom Request in Zapier. I have looked at this example [Curl Command via Zapier to Create Stripe Invoice with Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56485664/curl-command-via-zapier-to-create-stripe-invoice-with-params) but it's not really working as I'm getting an Error Message: "The app returned "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing". This usually happens when your Zap is missing a required field or a field value isn't in a recognized format." We made a request to api.stripe.com and received (400) Bad Request.

[This is how my Custom Request looks like in Zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ja6m7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The "Data" section in your request needs to be in url-encoded format since that what you specified in the content-type of the header section. So, change to this format:
charge=ch123456&reason=test
Better alternative would be to use Zapier's POST request instead of the Zapier custom request.
Like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/p13IA.jpg
And your post would look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/77swe.jpg
It's much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem after looking at logs in Stripe. "type": "invalid_request_error" pointed me in the right direction. I was trying to use the refund object "charge". We are using Stripe Checkout so "payment_intent" must be used instead. All good now! This is a working Zap that will create a refund on a Payment Intent.

[This is a working Zap that will create a refund on a Payment Intent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MOM3.jpg)